# Javascript - Grouping Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I already figured out the way to grouping object by its category using the code below:

```
  let groupBy = (element, key) => {
    return element.reduce((value, x) => {
          (value[x[key]] = value[x[key]] || []).push(x);
       return value;
     }, {});
   }; 
  let items = groupBy(results, 'category')
```

And, the result would be like so:

```
{
    "Administration": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Village Boundary",
            "color_prop": "#000000",
            "shp_prop": "Batu Ampar"
        },
        {
            "shp_name": "Village Boundary",
            "color_prop": "#FFFFFF",
            "shp_prop": "Sungai Jawi"
        }
    ],
    "Land_use": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Land Use 2019",
            "color_prop": "#000000",
            "shp_prop": "Grassland"
        },
   ]
}
```

I want to group them again by merging the `color_prop` and `shp_prop` to an array inside the object like below:

```
{
    "Administration": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Village Boundary",
            "color_prop": ["#000000","#FFFFFF"],
            "shp_prop": ["Batu Ampar","Sungai Jawi"]
        },
    ],
    "Land_use": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Land Use 2019",
            "color_prop": ["#000000"],
            "shp_prop": ["Grassland"]
        },
    ]
 }
```

I really appreciate it if someone could help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Is the `shp_name` the same for all items in a group? You are grouping by `category`, which means that only the `category` property of an item is guaranteed to be the same. In theory items within a group could have different `shp_name`s.

Comment: Hi, `shp_name` supposed to be unique but it was duplicated follow the `color_prop` length while looping process. That's why I am looking for the solution to avoid that. Btw, I joined 3 MySQL tables which area categroy, shapefile, and style. Category consist of shapefiles, each shapefile has some properties and colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a helper that converts "rows" into "columns".

```
function toColumns(rows) {
  const columns = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(rows[0]);
  for (const key of keys) columns[key] = [];
  for (const row of rows) {
    for (const key of keys) {
      columns[key].push(row[key]);
    }
  }
  return columns;
}
```

This helper converts a structure like:

```
[
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
]
```

Into:

```
{ a: [1, 3], b: [2, 4] }
```

With this helper defined you can convert your groups into the desired structure in the following manner:

```
for (const category in items) {
  const columns = toColumns(items[category]);
  // use the shp_name of the first item instead of an array
  columns.shp_name = columns.shp_name[0];
  items[category] = columns;
}
```

```js
function toColumns(rows) {
  const columns = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(rows[0]);
  for (const key of keys) columns[key] = [];
  for (const row of rows) {
    for (const key of keys) {
      columns[key].push(row[key]);
    }
  }
  return columns;
}

const items = {
    "Administration": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Village Boundary",
            "color_prop": "#000000",
            "shp_prop": "Batu Ampar"
        },
        {
            "shp_name": "Village Boundary",
            "color_prop": "#FFFFFF",
            "shp_prop": "Sungai Jawi"
        }
    ],
    "Land_use": [
        {
            "shp_name": "Land Use 2019",
            "color_prop": "#000000",
            "shp_prop": "Grassland"
        },
   ]
}

for (const category in items) {
  const columns = toColumns(items[category]);
  columns.shp_name = columns.shp_name[0];
  items[category] = columns;
}

console.log(items);
```

Replace `items[category] = columns` with `result[category] = columns` (where `result` is defined as `const result = {}` before the loop) if you don't want to mutate the original object.